# Requral для поля float

Tags: javascript, php, регулярные-выражения

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
/[^ \   \.  0-9]/ig
```

Нужно запретить вводить точку повторно.
Например 
1545.55 -> true
15424.55.44 -> false

короче нужно сделать примерно это
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `^\d+(?:\.\d+)?$`? ([Демо](https://regex101.com/r/PVeCL3/1)).

Comment: Но это выражение запрещает 1-у точку и разрешает 2-е.

Comment: Как раз то, о чём вы просили.

Comment: Посмотрите добавленную фотографию.

Comment: Вы перепутали ) там написано нужно запретить вводить точку повторно, т.е  запретить вводить 2 или более раз.

Comment: Регулярные выражения ничего не запрещают, они только находят совпадения шаблона в тексте или нет. В зависимости от того, найден текст или нет, можно разрешить какое-то действие или нет в *коде*. Приведите ваш код.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('input', e => {
  e.target.value.replace(/^(-?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]*)/, (m, p1) => {
    e.target.value = p1;
  });
});
```

```html
<input type="text">
```